# How do I add a user of my module to the coin contract with (coin.create-account) in a way that is similar to (coin.transfer-create)?

Tags: javascript, pact-lang

I have a module that some users may not have any KDA in their account, and thus don't exist on the coin contract. To prove ownership of a token, I am using `(enforce-guard (at "guard" (coin.details account)))` which returns `"with-read: row not found: k:9584f4...` if the user does not exist on the coin contract.

I want to call (coin.create-account) on behalf of a user of my module, so that when I check (enforce-guard), the response is valid, and afterwards the user exists on the coin contract just like if they had received KDA in their wallet.

From my understanding, I would call `coin.create-account "k:9584f4..." (read-keyset "k:9584f4...")` and then pay the gas, and they would then exist on the coin contract without having any KDA. I think my problem is: Where can I get the keyset to pass into `(read-keyset)` if my user is calling the contract through a front-end?

More directly: where do I get the guard to pass into coin.create-account? [image: create-account in chainweaver]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to fill out the parameters you need to define a keyset first in the ENV tab. Type a name and select a key like this:

[image: define keyset]

then open the module explorer and the token you want to create the account on and reference the keyset:

[image: create-account]

If you need to perform the same steps from code take a look at the example from the docs that does exactly that: https://docs.kadena.io/build/frontend/pact-lang-api-cookbook#create-account